# Django nltk view format proper response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nltk

I have a view that must return extracted nouns and verbs from my Task objects:

```
@api_view(['GET'])        
def test(request):

    verbs=[]
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
    print(serializer.data)

    text = ''.join([' '.join([str(y) for y in x.values()]) for x in serializer.data])

    text = nltk.word_tokenize(str(text)) #str(text)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)

    return Response(filter(lambda x:x[1]=='VB', tags))
```

my print statement prints:

```
[OrderedDict([(u'id', 17), ('title', u'browse through the list of books'), ('how_often', u'DO'), ('how_important_task', u'EI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', False), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u''), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 1L)]), OrderedDict([(u'id', 18), ('title', u'search for a book'), ('how_often', u'DS'), ('how_important_task', u'EI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', False), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u'RI'), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 1L)]), OrderedDict([(u'id', 19), ('title', u'request a book'), ('how_often', u'WO'), ('how_important_task', u'RI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', None), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u''), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 2L)]), OrderedDict([(u'id', 26), ('title', u'check latest arrivals of the books'), ('how_often', u'MO'), ('how_important_task', u'LI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', None), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u''), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 1L)])]
```

There are total 4 Task objects. Right now I am extracting nouns/verbs only from object values and ignoring keys.

What I want to achieve further is I do not want to check nouns or verbs from all the values but only three fields i.e. *title*, *role* and *tools_used*.

I would like to return data from this view to be something like:

```
[
    {
        "title":[nouns:[],verbs:[]],
        "role": [nouns:[], verbs:[]],
        "tools_used": [nouns:[], verbs:[]],

    },
    {
        "title":[nouns:[],verbs:[]],
        "role": [nouns:[], verbs:[]],
        "tools_used": [nouns:[], verbs:[]],

    }
]
```

For each task object and for each field of interest, I want array/list of nouns and verbs.

I am not sure how I can limit my for loops to these only 3 fields and then subsequently format my response. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it:

```
def get_nn_vb(text):
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(str(text))
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    nn = [x[0] for x in tags if x[1] == 'NN']
    vb = [x[0] for x in tags if x[1] == 'VB']
    return {'nouns': nn, 'verbs': vb}

nltk_keys = ['title', 'role', 'tools_used']
data = []
for x in serializer.data:
     nn_vb = {k: get_nn_vb(v) for k, v in x.items() if k in nltk_keys}
     data.append(nn_vb)
return Response(data)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! Sadly though it is throwing `AttributeError: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: please try it now

Comment: Amazing!! You saved me enough times in last couple of days!

Comment: Not related to your solution but nltk library doesn't seem to return correct values, for example in nouns I got browse, search etc.

Comment: as i can understand without `to` nltk think it nouns

Comment: Oh that's interesting!